# Is there an equivalent to .text() with attr()

Tags: jquery

Is there an equivalent to `text()` with `attr()`?

Change text of `<h1></h1>` with `attr()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The descendant nodes, including text nodes, of an element are just that: Nodes.

They are not attributes. You can not use `attr` to access or modify them.